# Java Constructor not working within same package

Tags: java

a simple one:

I am trying to use a constructor to create objects, but my objects are created empty. The constructor lives in a different class within the same package.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Initialize all data:
    ArrayList<Airport_example> all_airports = new ArrayList<Airport_example>(); 

    Airport_example perth = new Airport_example("01","Perth","PER","Australia","WST");
    Airport_example brisbane = new Airport_example("02","Brisbane","BNE","Australia","EST");

    //Add airports to ArrayList
    all_airports.add(perth);
    all_airports.add(brisbane);

            //debugging
    System.out.println(all_airports);
}
```

The constructor in a separate class looks like this:

```
public class Airport_example extends HashMap<String,String> {

//list of variables

private String airportID;
private String city;
private String code3;
private String country;
private String timezone;

// constructor to initialize objects
public Airport_example(String airportID, String city, String code3, String country, String timezone) {
    // Constructor variable initialization
    this.airportID = airportID;
    this.city = city;
    this.code3 = code3;
    this.country = country;
    this.timezone = timezone;

}
```

}

The System.out.println statement returns an empty array. Have I missed a simple trick here?

```
[{}, {}]
```

Comment: Why do you expect `HashMap.toString()` to know about the private fields of `Airport_example`? Moreover, why do you extend `HashMap` in the first place?

Comment: Why would you extend a Hashmap?

Comment: The constructor works fine, by the way...

Comment: The "trick" is that you need to overload `toString` in your airport class.  But as others have pointed out, it is probably a BAD IDEA to extend `HashMap`.  (Since when does an "airport" need to act as a general purpose name-value mapping?  This smells of incorrect OO modeling to me.)

Comment: Another problem is that your choice of class name is poor.  1) You are modeling an "airport", not an "airport example".  2) The classname violates Java identifier conventions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor works fine; the problem is that you are extending a `HashMap` and expecting it to know the contents of the private fields of the `Airport_example` subclass. To have your print statements work as you intend them to, you have to override the [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method.

I would recommend changing your code to the following:

```
public class Airport_example {

private String airportID;
private String city;
private String code3;
private String country;
private String timezone;

public Airport_example(String airportID, String city, String code3, String country, String timezone) {
    this.airportID = airportID;
    this.city = city;
    this.code3 = code3;
    this.country = country;
    this.timezone = timezone;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    // replace the string you want each object to print out
    return this.airportID + ", " + this.city + ", " + this.code3 + ", " + this.country + ", " + this.timezone;
}
```

The reason it's printing an empty array is that it's currently calling `HashMap`'s `toString`, and, as you don't define any of the `HashMap` fields, it's treating it as an empty `HashMap`.